# Errors With Sending Login Packet to Minecraft Server in Python

Tags: sockets, minecraft, python-2.x

I have the following script, which I found online, in Python. What it does is tries to connect to a MineCraft server, first by sending a 'handshake', then sending a login request. The protocol specs can be found here: http://wiki.vg/Protocol

Anyway, the python script works fine. However, I think the second packet is encoded wrong, as when it is sent, nothing appears on the server console. The player isn't connected or anything. It just eventually times out and closes the connection due to the 'client' not logging in in time.

Basically, anyway who has experience with struct.pack() should be able to help me here. I have commented the line where I am unsure of whether I have encoded everything right. The detailed information on packing the data is shown in the link above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm pretty clueless with encoding/packing data. :(

Here's the code

```
import struct

import socket

import time

import urllib

import urllib2


host = str(raw_input('What is the host ip: '))

port = int(raw_input('What is the server port: '))

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host, port))


usrnm = str(raw_input('What is your username: '))

psswrd = str(raw_input('What is your password: '))


logindata = {'user':usrnm, 'password':psswrd, 'version':'12'}

data = urllib.urlencode(logindata)

print('Sending data to login.minecraft.net...')

req = urllib2.Request('https://login.minecraft.net', data)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

returndata = response.read() 

returndata = returndata.split(":")

mcsessionid = returndata[3]

del req

del returndata

print("Session ID: " + mcsessionid)

data = {'user':usrnm,'host':host,'port':port}


enc_user = data['user'].encode('utf-16BE')

packfmt = '>bih{}shiibBB'.format(len(enc_user))

packetbytes = struct.pack(packfmt, 1, 23, len(data['user']), enc_user, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

stringfmt = u'%(user)s;%(host)s:%(port)d'

string = stringfmt % data

structfmt = '>bh'

packetbytes = struct.pack(structfmt, 2, len(string))+string.encode('utf-16BE')

s.send(packetbytes)

connhash = s.recv(1024)

print("Connection Hash: " + connhash)

print('Sending data to http://session.minecraft.net/game/joinserver.jsp?user=' + usrnm + '&sessionId=' + mcsessionid + '&serverId=' + connhash + '...')

req = urllib.urlopen('http://session.minecraft.net/game/joinserver.jsp?user=' + usrnm + '&sessionId=' + mcsessionid + '&serverId=' + connhash)

returndata = req.read()

if(returndata == 'OK'):

    print('session.minecraft.net says everything is okay, proceeding to send data to server.')

else:

    print('Oops, something went wrong.')

time.sleep(5)

# All above here works perfectly.

enc_user = data['user'].encode('utf-16BE')

packfmt = '>bih{}shiibBB'.format(len(enc_user))

packetbytes = struct.pack(packfmt, 1, 23, len(data['user']), enc_user, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

#This line is probably where something's going wrong:

packetbytes = struct.pack('>bih', 1, 23, len(data['user'])) + data['user'].encode('utf-16BE') + struct.pack('>hiibBB', 2,0,0,0,0,0)

print(len(packetbytes))

print('Sending ' + packetbytes + ' to server.')

s.send(packetbytes)



while True:

    data = s.recv(1024)

    if data:

        print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you're sending the length of the string, which is the number of characters. Instead, you should be sending the number of bytes in the encoded string. Also, you should use "!" instead of ">" for clarity's sake, as "!" is used to indicate "network order", which this is. So this...

```
structfmt = '>bh'

packetbytes = struct.pack(structfmt, 2, len(string))+string.encode('utf-16BE')
```

... gets changed to this...

```
structfmt = '!bh'

encoded = string.encode('utf-16BE')

packetbytes = struct.pack(structfmt, 2, len(encoded))+encoded
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Documents and Settings\matthew\Desktop\Minecraft_Connect.py", line 111, in <module>
data = s.recv(1024)
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine `

Comment: Ah, sorry for being away for five days. Tonsillectomy :/ Does it throw this exception every time?